# magento community extension update problem

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, upgrade

I created a paid community extension with `version 1.0.0,` and in this moment I have an upgrade for it with `version 1.0.1.` I add this version in Magento Store at http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/extension/extension_version/ but not shown in admin panel after I press `"Check for Updates"` button.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Magento Connect only provides the infrastructure for free community extensions - it does not allow you to install (or upgrade) non free extensions.

Since you are listing a paid extension the version will only show under "Release Notes" tab in your Magento Connect listing.

Update notifications are up to you to implement (if you built it into your extension just do make sure that you don't perform the check on every admin page view and that if your endpoint is not available it does not unnecessarily slow down the admin).